# How to connect multiple user using webrtc?

Tags: signalr, webrtc

- I am using asp.core for webrtc signaling server.
- using this i am trying to make group video call.
- Right now i am send the every user with new offer.
- Like A,B,C have three user when A send request for video call so B receive offer connect with A and start the call.
- And then A again send offer for C and C receive the offer and send answer and connect with A.
- So Now on this time
  A Connect With B separate peer connection and
  A Connect With C separate peer connection
- but how to connect B and C for each other for group video call
- i can try to when A connect With Both means B and C
- then B send offer C and connect with each other
- so it's possible or not